# Get the index of array of picturebox clicked

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating some picturebox dynamically and click event for picturebox as follows

```
Image myImage = Image.FromFile("image/Untitled6.png"); 
PictureBox[] txtTeamNames = new PictureBox[5];        

for (int i = 0; i < txtTeamNames.Length; i++)
{
  var txt = new PictureBox();
  txtTeamNames[i] = txt;                
  txtTeamNames[i].Image = myImage;                
  txtTeamNames[i].Height = 53;
  txtTeamNames[i].Width = 48;                
  this.panel1.Controls.Add(txtTeamNames[i]);                
  txtTeamNames[i].Visible = true;
  txtTeamNames[i].Click += new EventHandler(this.clcikeventhandle);
}
```

When someone clicks on any picture box, how do I find its array index and name?

```
void clickEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
  //???
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the `PictureBox` via the `sender` argument. So try this:

```
PictureBox[] txtTeamNames;

void YourMethod()
{
    Image myImage = Image.FromFile("image/Untitled6.png"); 
    txtTeamNames = new PictureBox[5];        
    //The same as your code
}   

void clcikeventhandle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    int index = txtTeamNames.IndexOf(sender As PictureBox);
}
```

**EDIT: Approach #2**

But if you are not happy with declaring that array in the class scope you can try this approach:

```
//Same as your code
for (int i = 0; i < txtTeamNames.Length; i++)
{
    //Save as your code
    txtTeamNames[i].Tag = i;                        // ADD THIS LINE
}
```

Then:

```
void clcikeventhandle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    int index = int.Parse((sender as PictureBox).Tag.ToString());
}
```

Comment: +1. Now it's only about scope. If OP is okay with declaring `txtTeamNames` at class level, this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion - create a custom class, which inherits from `PictureBox`. It will have an extra `Index` property. And you can set it between these two lines:

```
txtTeamNames[i].Visible = true;
//assign the index here
txtTeamNames[i].Click += new EventHandler(this.clcikeventhandle);
```

like so:

```
txtTeamNames[i].Index = i;
```

Then in the handler:

```
void clickEventHandle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  PictureBox pbox = sender As PictureBox;
  int index = pbox.Index();
  string name = pbox.Name();
}
```

You keep the same scope of variables, which may be useful if you are concerned about it. If you are okay with upgrading scope of `txtTeamNames` to class level, see [another answer by **Hossein Narimani Rad**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15748476/897326).

Comment: I'm interested to know how you create a link exactly to my answer? How it is possible? Thanks.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad: there is a share link below your answer. :)

Comment: Wow! It seems I've never noticed it!

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace your_name_project
{
    public partial class Form_Begin : Form
    {
        PictureBox[] pictureBoxs = new PictureBox[6];
        public Form_Begin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pictureBoxs[0] = pictureBox1; pictureBoxs[1] = pictureBox2; pictureBoxs[2] = pictureBox3;
            pictureBoxs[3] = pictureBox4; pictureBoxs[4] = pictureBox5;   pictureBoxs[5] = pictureBox6;     
        }
//continue 
        List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox>();

            private void buttonX1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <3; i++)
                {
                    pictureBoxs[i].Image =your_name_project.Properties.Resources.image_1;// load image1 and Image_2from resource in property of picturebox  
                }
                for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    pictureBoxs[i].Image = your_name_project.Properties.Resources.Image_2;
                }
            } 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the 1st approach cited above, but it did not work for me. I needed to change the syntax in order to work. I am unsure why, but my way for approach 1 to work would be:

```
PictureBox[] txtTeamNames;

void YourMethod()
{
    Image myImage = Image.FromFile("image/Untitled6.png"); 
    txtTeamNames = new PictureBox[5];        
    //The same as your code
}   

void clcikeventhandle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    int index = Array.IndexOf(txtTeamNames, sender); //DIFFERENT HERE
}
```

If anyone has an idea...