# C# - Click event sending a value

Tags: c#, picturebox

I'm using a for-loop to add values into an array of PictureBox and binding a click event to each one. I'm looking for a way of getting the data of a PictureBox after clicking on it. Since it's an array, I was thinking of sending the value of the loop counter, which would identify which one was clicked.

My code looks like this:

```
PictureBox[] picboxes = new PictureBox[result];
for (int i = 0; i < results; i++)
{
    picboxes[i] = new PictureBox();
    picboxes[i].ImageLocation = @FormIni.RetRes((i * 5) + 5 + i);
    picboxes[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(PictureBoxes_Click);
}

private void PictureBoxes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "here I need the value of the picboxes[i] image location";
}
```

It can seem stupid, but I thought of something like:

`picboxes[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(PictureBoxes_Click(i))`

and

`private void PictureBoxes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, int i)`

In short: when I click in a PictureBox created in a array via code, how do I get its values (inside the click event handler)?

**EDIT!**

Sorry for finding it only after making this question, but I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748429/get-the-index-of-array-of-picturebox-clicked) solution and it may apply to my case, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try do do this

```
PictureBox[] picboxes = new PictureBox[result];
for (int i = 0; i < results; i++)
{
    picboxes[i] = new PictureBox();
    picboxes[i].Name = (i+1).ToString();
    picboxes[i].ImageLocation = @FormIni.RetRes((i * 5) + 5 + i);
    picboxes[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(PictureBoxes_Click);
}

private void PictureBoxes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox p = (PictureBox)sender;
    string j = p.Name;
    label1.Text = j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following (anoynomous method) lambda expression

```
 picboxes[i].Click += (sender, eventArguments) => PictureBoxes_Click(sender, eventArguments, i);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've never used lambda expression before, so it's confused for me. =/

Comment: It makes coding much easier in my opinion. Try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use Tag

```
PictureBox[] picboxes = new PictureBox[result];
for (int i = 0; i < results; i++)
{
    picboxes[i] = new PictureBox();
    picboxes[i].Tag = (i+1).ToString();
    picboxes[i].ImageLocation = @FormIni.RetRes((i * 5) + 5 + i);
    picboxes[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(PictureBoxes_Click);
}

private void PictureBoxes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox p = (PictureBox)sender;
    string j = p.tag.tostring();
    label1.Text = j;
}
```