# Finding index of clicked image in a dynamically generated array of pictureboxes

Tags: c#

I have code that creates a row of 5 pictureboxes at runtime. I have added (I think) the code to add a click event handler to each picturebox as it is created.

```
int xPos = 95;                                                  
      for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)                         
      {
        keepImage[index] = new PictureBox();                          
        keepImage[index].Width = 120;                                 
        keepImage[index].Height = 41;                     
        keepImage[index].Left = xPos;                      
        keepImage[index].Top = 360;

        keepImage[index].Click += new EventHandler(keepImage_Click);

        keepImage[index].BackColor = Color.Transparent;               
        keepImage[index].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;    
        this.Controls.Add(keepImage[index]);                          
        xPos += 125;                                                  
      }
```

The code works - it creates and displays the pictureboxes. I have been looking on here to find out how to find which one of the pictureboxes is clicked on...

```
public void keepImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      PictureBox index = sender as PictureBox;
      // identify which button was clicked and perform necessary actions
      Debug.Write(index);
    }
```

This code was taken from a solution found on here, but how do I adapt it for my needs? I have tried but so far, no luck.
At runtime the debug shows ***System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox, SizeMode: CenterImage*** but not the actual index.

Thanks for any suggestions.

**EDIT**
After trying one of the solutions mentioned in the comments, I now get the following error...

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the index of array of picturebox clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748429/get-the-index-of-array-of-picturebox-clicked)

Comment: Thanks @SelimYıldız, I am going to try it now.

Comment: @SelimYıldız not yet. I am using Approach 2 on the suggested solution, but I get a context error on the PictureBox in the event handler method.

Comment: It seems typo, it should be `as` instead of `As`.

Comment: @SelimYıldız PERFECT... Works great now. I copied & pasted from solution, never spotted the typo. Thank you thank you :)

Comment: I have added an answer which including type issue, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow second approach from [Get the index of array of picturebox clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15748476/5519709). But there is a typo issue with this answer it should be `(sender as PictureBox)`.

So in your case, you can use [`Control.Tag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag) property to store index of pictures as:

```
int xPos = 95;                                                  
for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)                         
{
    //Other codes
    keepImage[index].Tag = index;  //Set tag from index 
    this.Controls.Add(keepImage[index]);                          
    xPos += 125;                                                  
}
```

Then click event would be like:

```
public void keepImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = int.Parse((sender as PictureBox).Tag.ToString());
    Debug.Write(index);
}
```